# client project is running on port x and server api end points are running on port y. How does AJAX know where webapi end point

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I just started working with .net and I can give complete webapi endpoint urls to make AJAX calls or give relative url. How does client project know where to locate webapi endpoints when using relative URL ?

Client AJAX current call:

```
$.ajax({
                             url: localhost:3227/api/form/post,
                             contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                             type: "POST",
                             dataType: "json",
                             data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                             success: function (resp) {
                                 console.log("Updated successfully!");                                 },
                             error: function (request, status, error) {
                                 console.log(request.responseText + ' Error:' + error.message);
}
});
```

What I want to do:

```
$.ajax({
                             url: /api/form/post,
                             contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                             type: "POST",
                             dataType: "json",
                             data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                             success: function (resp) {
                                 console.log("Updated successfully!");                                 },
                             error: function (request, status, error) {
                                 console.log(request.responseText + ' Error:' + error.message);
}
});
```

How does AJAX call know where `localhost:3227/api/form/post` is if I remove `localhost:3227` and only keep `/api/form/post`
Is it in some project configuration that I don't know about ?

Comment: "I just went to the ... to buy ..." How would you know where I went and what I bought? Exactly, you won't know. Why do you expect a system to know where to go if you do not tell it where to go?

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I am not expecting it to know. What I want to know is how is it getting resolved. I don't want to hard code it in a config file because, a server host URL will be different. I wanted to know the mechanism ? If you know please explain. Why a negative point ?

Comment: Because the question is very broad and can be answered in many different ways. It's not a concrete question.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I am a noob and probably don't have as much knowledge as you do, but I a here to learn and can you please help or direct me to a resource. Negative voting probably will take my ability to even comment. Thanks Anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config file add, 
var api_url = localhost:3227;

and then,

```
$.ajax({
                             url: api_url+ '/api/form/post',
                             contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                             type: "POST",
                             dataType: "json",
                             data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                             success: function (resp) {
                                 console.log("Updated successfully!");                                 },
                             error: function (request, status, error) {
                                 console.log(request.responseText + ' Error:' + error.message);
}
});
```

Comment: I researched more on this and @Stephan Bijzitter and you are both correct.